# Read imag File image in oracle form

Tags: oracle10g

I want to upload image in oracle form and I used this code

```
READ_IMAGE_FILE('C:\DevSuiteHome_2\forms\kalam.jpg','JPG','XXFLT_DRIVERS.DRIVER_IMAGE');
```

in upload button but whenever I pressed the upload button I got error

```
'FRM-47109:Cannot locate image file'.
```